# Javascript functions work in firefox and chrome but not IE9

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I have some simple functions in javascript which work fine in most browser except IE9. I have heard Ie9 is fussy about commas etc. But I cannot spot any obvious problems. Can anyone of you guys and gals shed any light? Full code below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false);


      function load() {
        //dom loaded


        var elUserId = document.getElementById("user_id"); 
        var elPasswordId = document.getElementById("password");
        var elLoginMsg = document.getElementById("usernameMsg");
        var elPasswordMsg = document.getElementById("passwordMsg");
        var elIncreaseFontSize = document.getElementById("increaseFont");
        var elResetFontSize = document.getElementById("resetFont");
        var elChangeContrast = document.getElementById("changeContrast");
        var elResetContrast = document.getElementById("resetContrast");
        var logInbox = document.getElementById("loginBox");
        var helpWithBB = document.getElementById("helpWithBB");
        var fontUp = '135%';
        var fontReset = '100%';
        var black = '#000000';
        var white = '#ffffff';
        var divReset ='415px';
        var divChange ='525px';
        var txtSizeChange ='40.5em';
        var txtReset ='42em';


        elLoginMsg.style.display ='none';
        elPasswordMsg.style.display = 'none';

        elPasswordId.addEventListener("focus", function(){
            showText(elPasswordMsg);
        }, false);

        elUserId.addEventListener("click", function(){
            showText(elLoginMsg);
        }, false);

        elResetFontSize.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //pass size change and element affected to be manipulated
        //resetTextSize(fontReset,logInbox,elPasswordMsg);
        changeTextSize(fontReset,logInbox,elPasswordMsg,divReset,txtReset);
        });

        elChangeContrast.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //pass size change and element affected to be manipulated
        changeContrast(logInbox, helpWithBB, black, white);
        });

        elResetContrast.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.location.reload(true);
        });



        elIncreaseFontSize.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //pass size change and element affected to be manipulated
        changeTextSize(fontUp,logInbox,elPasswordMsg,divChange,txtSizeChange);
        });


        function changeContrast(mainDiv, secDiv, txtColor, bkColor){

        secDiv.style.background = bkColor;
        mainDiv.style.background = bkColor;

        showText(elPasswordMsg);
        showText(elLoginMsg);

        elLoginMsg.style.color = txtColor;
        elPasswordMsg.style.color = txtColor;

            var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            anchors[i].style.color = txtColor;
            }

            var para = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
            for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            para[i].style.color = txtColor;
            }
        }

        function changeTextSize(fontUp, elDiv, msg, divH, msgT){
        document.body.style.fontSize=fontUp;
        elDiv.style.height = divH;
        msg.style.top = msgT;
        }

        function showText(id){
            id.style.display ='block';
        }

      }

    </script>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the third parameter (`useCapture`) in some of your calls to `addEventListener()` but other than that nothing is obviously wrong. I know that Firefox has only started supporting `addEventListener()` without a third parameter within the last year, so it's possible IE 9 doesn't support it.

**Update**

So much for that theory. Two parameters seems fine in IE 9: http://jsfiddle.net/xZRy7/

Comment: thanks for your input. I put the third param in anyway. The quest continues!